# how to set the output type List<string> in a middleware in .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I have this middleware class when I want to show a `List<string>` in the output:

```
namespace WebAspNetCore2_1
{
    public class LearningMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<LearningMiddleware> _logger_log;
        private readonly List<string> logger;

        public LearningMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,ILogger<LearningMiddleware> logger_log)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger_log = logger_log;

            List<string> _logger = new List<string>
                                       {
                                           ("EUR/USD"),
                                           ("1.0500")
                                       };

            logger = _logger;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            _logger_log.Log(Microsoft.Extensions .Logging.LogLevel.Information,"information of logger",logger[0]);
            return _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I have debugged my code but seen to be correct, my `List<>` is filled, I don't know why the compiler is throwing this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, give the 'logger' parameter a non-null default value.

i thought was the order declaration in StartUp, but not

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       // app.UseLearningMiddleware();            
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMiddleware<LearningMiddleware>();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

link in video for detail evidence: https://youtu.be/2FoLvhLweYo

Comment: I just want to confirm that have you tried to use `ILoggerFactory`? although it looks not related to the error message.

Comment: no i'am not using ILoggerFactory

Comment: maybe you need a rebuild? sorry in advance..

Comment: is it possible that the exception doesn't happen in this middleware? could you pls add breakpoint the locate the line?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code in my side but it worked well... I created a new asp.net core 2.1 MVC project and create a middleware. In StartUp.cs, I put `app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();` just before `app.UseMvc(routes =>`

[image]

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    // You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions package into your project
    public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<MyMiddleware> _logger_log;
        private readonly List<string> logger;

        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<MyMiddleware> logger_log)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger_log = logger_log;
            List<string> _logger = new List<string>
                                       {
                                           ("EUR/USD"),
                                           ("1.0500")
                                       };
            logger = _logger;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            _logger_log.Log(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information, "information of logger", logger[0]);
            return _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added the code on my code StartUp, but the error persist

Comment: i have delete middleware invokation and the error is the same, it´s seen something file damage in my proyect

Comment: hmmm, I can't do more things on this case.... maybe you can try to create another .net core 2.1 project and test this middleware seperately?

Comment: something happened with Program.cs when add a code of test that i later commented, finally i created a new proyect and add my middleware class and its work ! thanks you

Comment: that's good to hear that